# $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}[f(x+1)-f(x-1)]$ when $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f'(x) =a$

Tags: limits, proof-verification

Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ s.t. $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f'(x) =a$ then

It is required to get the value of $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}[f(x+1)-f(x-1)]$

---

**Solution**

$f(x) = ax + C$ when $x \to \infty$.

When $x \to \infty$ $f(x+1) = ax+a+C$ and $f(x-1)=ax-a+C$. Thus,

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}[f(x+1)-f(x-1)] = ax+a+C-ax+a-C = 2a$

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say $f(x)=ax+C$ when $x\to\infty$. $~f$ need not ever be linear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your solution you considered only a particular case. 
What happens when $f$ is not a linear map?

Hint. Use the Mean Value Theorem: given any real number $x$, there is $t_x\in (x-1,x+1)$ such that
$$\frac{f(x+1)-f(x-1)}{(x+1)-(x-1)}=f'(t_x).$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Just subtract and add $f(x) $ and then by mean value theorem you can easily see that the expression tends to $2a$.